# Capture The First Name Begin With .Bundle

Tags: bash, awk, terminal, grep

I Have Input Like

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle/Contents/version.plist 
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle/Contents/Resources/brtool 
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/brtools.bundles/Contents/Version.plist
```

I Need The Outputs to be
(The Text upto First Occurrence of .bundle)

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle
```

Comment: And I don't have input like that. Now what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{print $1 FS}' FS='.bundle' file
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle
```

For just lines containing `.bundle`:

```
$ awk '$0~FS{print $1 FS}' FS='.bundle' file
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` :

```
sed 's/\(\.bundle\).*$/\1/' Input
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `sed 's=bundle/.*=bundle='`.

Comment: `\.bundle` would include the requested full stop

Answer (score 1):

Using `egrep -o`

```
 grep -oP '.*?\.bundle(?=/)' file

/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle
```

#### Working Demo: http://ideone.com/iT6VGy

Comment: @Downvoter: May I please know why it was down-voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote but your `.*` is too greedy in my tests. Last row: `/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/brtools.bundle`

Comment: @svante: It worked for my on my OSX that's why I posted this. It can always be made: `egrep -o '^.+?\.bundle' file`

Comment: I tried that too, no luck (egrep 2.14 on Ubuntu 13.04).
Works: `grep -oP '^.+?\.bundle' Input`

Comment: @svante: My Linux shows `GNU grep 2.6.3` and both commands (.* and .+?) worked on Linux also.

Comment: I did, but even there the last line has TWO `.bundle` . I'm confused. Got `grep -oP ...` to work on my box so I'll give you my vote. http://ideone.com/1wpVBT

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39008/discussion-between-svante-and-anubhava)

Comment: @anubhava your working demo shows the solution **not** working. The non-greediness of `?` is not part of ERE it's PCRE so you need `-P`.

Comment: @sudo_O: Yes that's correct, edited. New demo: http://ideone.com/iT6VGy

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex match, with groups, for python: http://regex101.com/r/yL3xZ5

Here is a simple example with `awk`

```
❯ awk '/\.bundle/{ gsub(/\.bundle\/.*$/, ".bundle"); print; }' <<_EOF_
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle/Contents/version.plist
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle/Contents/Resources/brtool
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/brtools.bundles/Contents/Version.plist
_EOF_
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle
❯
```

Another in `sed`:

```
❯ sed -e 's@\(\.bundle\)/.*$@\1@' <<_EOF_
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle/Contents/version.plist
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle/Contents/Resources/brtool
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/brtools.bundles/Contents/Version.plist
_EOF_
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle
❯
```

Another in pure `bash`:

```
❯ while read line; do echo ${line/.bundle\/*/.bundle}; done <<_EOF_
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle/Contents/version.plist
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle/Contents/Resources/brtool
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/brtools.bundles/Contents/Version.plist
_EOF_

/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle
❯
```

And the last, with `grep`

```
❯ grep -oP '^(.*?\.bundle)(?=/)' <<_EOF_
/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle/Contents/version.plist
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle/Contents/Resources/brtool
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/brtools.bundles/Contents/Version.plist
_EOF_

/System/Library/CoreServices/AOS.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/Br.bundle
/System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle
❯
```